# How to use @SerializedName annotation for post body object

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit2

I have created a api service interface

```java
package com.rohitkhatri.app.services;

import com.rohitkhatri.app.models.Login;
import com.rohitkhatri.app.models.User;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface ApiService {
    @POST("user/authenticate")
    Call<User> login(@Body Login login);
}
```

```java
package com.rohitkhatri.app.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Login {
    @SerializedName("country_code")
    private String countryCode;
    @SerializedName("mobile_no")
    private String mobileNo;
    private String otp;

    public Login(String countryCode, String mobileNo, String otp) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
        this.otp = otp;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public String getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public String getOtp() {
        return otp;
    }
}
```

And this is the request parameters required by the api:

```
{
    "country_code": "91",
    "mobile_no": "9XXXXXXXXX",
    "otp": "348783"
}
```

But when I log the request, It's sending the following json as body

```
{"countryCode":"91","mobileNo":"9XXXXXXXXX","otp":"348783"}
```

Because the name is different in java object and required by the api call, It's giving error.

Is there a way to use `@SerializedName` annotation or any other way to change it in the call?

My problem is, It's working when we use this model as response of the call, but If I want to send call and pass this object, the sending data doesn't include the serialized name of the field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize POJO to JSON with different names using GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547662/serialize-pojo-to-json-with-different-names-using-gson)

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/32547662/4806502

Comment: @Traabefi It's not duplicate, the reference you have posted, works when the object is used for response of a call, but If I'm making call, It doesn't serialize the name like `countryCode` to `country_code`

Comment: But the question is all about serialising not deserialising. Are you by the way using @Expose annotation ? Because you have to add it as well

Comment: @Traabefi Thank you so much, exposing fields with `@Expose` annotation worked perfect. :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please accept my answef then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the @Expose annotation too. It's often forgotten to use.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was all I needed.